# Receber valor de variavel e inserir varias linhas no MYSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

Tenho a seguinte variavel:

```
$ids = "758,749";
```

A tabela tem as colunas: id, id_prestador, aceite.

Ao rodar um script PHP, gostaria que ele fizesse algo assim:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (id, id_prestador, aceite) VALUES (null, $iddecadaprestador1, '0');
INSERT INTO tabela (id, id_prestador, aceite) VALUES (null, $iddecadaprestador2, '0');
```

Ou seja, a coluna id_prestador é varivel, sendo que cada valor está dentro da variavel $ids e os outros campos são fixos.

Comment: Campos separados por virgula ? 758 seria um $iddecadaprestador1 e 749 o outro $iddecadaprestador1?

Comment: Se id for pk e auto incremento, você nem precisa usar na sua query, agora no seu problema em especifico... basta dar um `$a = explode(",",$ids)` e fazer um `foreach($a as $id_prestador){ $Query = "seu insert".$id_prestador; } echo $Query;`

Comment: isos, cada numero seria um id

Comment: valeu @MarceloBoni funcionou certinho!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro você pode usar o `explode()` para quebrar entre as virgulas:

```
$array = explode(',', '758,749');
```

Isso vai gerar uma array contendo `758` e `749`, separados.

Depois, existem várias maneiras de inserir os valores no banco de dados. Uma delas é usando Prepared-Statement, supondo que utilize MySQLi:

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela (id_prestador, aceite) VALUES (?, '0')");

foreach($array as $idPrestador){
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $idPrestador);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
```

Se o `aceite` tiver um valor padrão de `0` você pode omitir ele da query. :)

Comment: apareceu a seguinte msg: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference na linha     $stmt->bind_param('si', $idPrestador, 0);

Comment: Não foi de novo Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in. to fazendo a conexão certa? $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('i', $idPrestador);`

Comment: @13dev, exato, alterei.